# With these two elements how can the isotope half-life be determined using first order kinetics?

Tags: isotopes

With these two elements how can the isotope half-life be determined using first order kinetics?

[nobelium-259](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_radioactive_isotopes_by_half-life) half-life recorded @ 58 minutes
[fermium-253](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_radioactive_isotopes_by_half-life) half-life recorded @ 3 days

Although I do not know, there is probably an average starting concentration that can probably be determined by the name of the element. Maybe in the comments someone can hook me up with some estimate averages so the expansion of the math could be given in the answer.

Comment: What is first order kinetics? Whatever it is, to correctly predict half-lifes full quantum mechanics is needed, as decay is an inherently quantum phenomenon.

Comment: I want to understand the rate of decay. From a formula based calculation instead of a "visual measurement".

Comment: @ACuriousMind Are quantum phenomenons formula based? Not that I'm limited to a formula based result.

Comment: The two isotopes you picked decay either by alpha emission or electron capture. Are you asking if there's a theoretical means of predicting the decay rate for one of those modes?

Comment: Nobelium 259 also undergoes significant spontaneous fission.

Comment: @bogeyc How about both methods? The defined result of 58 minutes came from some method. I want to see the method in action.

Comment: @Onlyheisgood. this is the publication of how the 58 minutes was determined: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375947473905204

Comment: @DavePhD Right you are.

Answer (score 5):

First order reaction kinetics only states that the system obeys the decay equation
$$\frac{d[X]}{dt}=-k[X],\quad k>0.$$
The solution is usually written
$$[X(t)]=[X_0]e^{-kt},$$
where $[X_0]$ is the starting concentration (or simply number of particles), but in terms of the half-life, $k=(\ln 2)/\tau_{1/2}$, so
$$[X(t)]=[X_0]2^{-t/\tau_{1/2}}.$$
So using kinetics, you'd need to know the concentrations/numbers of particles at two different times (or at least their ratio) to measure the half-life. Otherwise, as stated in the comments, you need the full quantum mechanical theory of nuclear kinetics, which is generally not referred to as first order kinetics.

Comment: other than number of particles at two different times, you could determine decay rate for a known number of particles at a single time (or during a single time interval), by observing alpha or beta decay or other decays per time interval.

Comment: I have read "first-order logic additionally covers predicates and quantification" verses "propositional logic". Here(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). Does that mean that "full quantum mechanical theory of nuclear kinetics" is of another form then that of the quantification covered by first-order logic?

Comment: The "first order" in propositional logic has little to do with "first order" in a physics context. The latter is concerned with linearized theories/formulas/approximations.

Comment: "first order" means that rate of reaction (decay) is proportional to amount of reactant (number of nuclei).